# JBoss Cli - query to return available methods

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x

JBoss Cli has a tab autocomplete function which shows the available methods/paths for the current directory. For example when I press tab after connecting to the server through the cli I get these options:

[image]

Then I can follow the path eg /deployment/ and tab again to see the next avaialbe methods/paths from there.

I am currently developing a standalone interface that communicates with JBoss via the native management api. I am looking for a query/operation I can run that will return these available methods/paths as actual result values?

I hope that makes sense. Does anyone know if this is possible?

EDIT: not sure how this slipped my mind but I can just run ls to display the directories. The available commands are shown by typing ":" then hitting tab. Its really these commands I need to get returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `:read-resource-description(operations=true)` and process the result in `result.operations`.

Another option would be to use tab complete to see the list or use the operation `:read-operation-names` and `read-operation-description` to see details about a specific operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply systemtrap. I'll give it a go first thing Monday. Although I'm pretty certain this is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: I forgot too there is http://wildscribe.github.io/ that describes operations and attributes as well.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins now has a place among my many bookmarks. Thanks James.